# How to display paragraph like content in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to develop an simple "Invoice" Windows application. I have bounded  the textboxes (Item, Description, MRP, Quantity, etc.) to `DataGridView` but data entered by user in the "Description" textbox (multiline) has to be displayed as it is in `GridView` which is not happening in my code.

My code:

```
private void DS_Invoice_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.allDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet4.AllData);
    this.itemDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet3.ItemData);
    this.custDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet2.CustData);
    groupBox1.Enabled = false;
    groupBox2.Hide();
    groupBox3.Show();
    groupBox3.Enabled = true;
    max();
    tb_inv_id.ReadOnly = true;
    tb_order_id.Text = "-";
    tb_net_amt.Text = "0";
    tb_amt.Text = "0";
}

private void btnAddJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Item Name", "Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Description", "Description");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Qauntity", "Qauntity");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Rate", "Rate");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Amount", "Amount");
    }
    // Add the text box values to a new row in the DataGridView
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { tbItemNm.Text, tbItemDscr.Text,
            tb_quantity.Text,tb_rate.Text,tb_amt.Text});
    MessageBox.Show("Item Added successfully..", "Add Job", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    tbItemNm.Clear();
    tbItemDscr.Clear();
    tb_quantity.Clear();
    tb_rate.Clear();
    tb_amt.Clear();
    tbItemNm.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example for wrapping text in grid view.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;width:100px");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?.  If the answer is useful to you, please do not forget to upvote and accept the answer. You can also downvote if you think that answer is wrong or not useful.